# Map a Y/N property to a boolean without breaking Link To Entities

Tags: .net, entity-framework-6, linq-to-entities

OK, I'm working with an OLD SQL database, old enough that originally you couldn't index bit fields.
So I have a bunch of tables with Y/N single char fields in them.

I've finally go the opportunity to move things into C#, and entity framework.

It would be really handy to be able to "convert" those into a Boolean field on the front end.
But when I do that, I break Linq to Entities when I query it.

e.g.

db.Carriers.Where(x => x.ActiveBool) dies.

db.Carriers.ToList().Where(x => x.ActiveBool) doesn't.
 But obviously, no query back to SQL, etc.

Is there a way to one of these (or something else clever/handy)

1. do a property mapping to treat the field as a bool
2. do a "proper" new property I can use
3. Add a method on the object I can call that doesn't break Linq to Entities

Answer (score 2):

You have a few options here.  If you can, you could update the database to have a Computed field and then you can query it that way.

You can create a [NotMapped] property for IsActive that does:

```
[NotMapped]
public bool IsActive 
{ 
    get { return Active == 'Y'; } 
    set { Active = value ? 'Y' : 'N'; } 
}
```

Then you can make "Active" field Internal to have it point to the DB but only work with this IsActive column on your model.

However, for actually filtering off of this field, you either have to use a computed column, view, or translate the IsActive boolean filter passed in from above to 'Y' or 'N'.  Otherwise, you could do some tricky Expression stuff under the covers make this conversion for you, but I don't think it would be worth that kind of effort.  A helper method would probably do.

```
char check = Helper.ConvertBoolToChar(entity.IsActive) (returns 'Y' or 'N')
...Where(a => a.Active == check)
```

Comment: OK, your "NotMapped" example is basically what I've got. I don't think the other examples cut down on complications either unfortunately.  Ah well.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

OK.  I think I've got at least a partial solution.

Add to (e.g. Units class)

```
       public static System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<Units, bool>> IsActive = x => ("Y".Equals(x.Active, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) && 
(x.Carriers == null || "Y".Equals(x.Carriers.Active, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

Then to filter

```
   l = l.Where(Data.Units.IsActive);
```

I couldn't figure out how to do a WHERE on 'a' that referenced navigation object 'a.B' as a separate step, but this should get me what I need.
Time to test it.

Yes.  That seems to work.